# Forked process keeps listening to the server's port

Tags: c++, c, posix, fork, port

This is light version of my code for executing commands:

```
void close_all_nonestandard_fds()
{
    struct rlimit fds_limit;
    int max_fd = 1024;
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &fds_limit) == 0) max_fd = fds_limit.rlim_cur;
    for(int i = 0; i <= max_fd; ++i) {
        if(i != STDERR_FILENO && i != STDOUT_FILENO && i != STDIN_FILENO) close(i);
    }
}

void exec_command(char* command, char*const* args)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid != 0)
    {
        if(pid == -1) throw_error("Failed to fork: %s", strerror(errno));
        // Parent
    }
    else
    {
        // Child
        close_all_nonestandard_fds();
        if(execv(command, args) == -1) throw_error("Failed to execv: %s", trerror(errno));
    }
}
```

The `exec_command` method is used in my server side application for running different kind of processes including daemon processes. But here I noticed a problem:

When server runs a child daemon process, then it (the server) being killed or crashed the child starts to listen to the port server was listening to.

So, how can I execute a command and be sure that it wouldn't keep port of the server busy after servers end (crash, death)?

Comment: How do you know that the child process is listening to the port?

Comment: BTW, you cannot close a non existing fd. That's most likely why your server crashes...

Comment: @Sdra, of course you can.  You'll get EBADF in errno.

Comment: @DietrichEpp using [netstat -ap | grep <port>]

Comment: Are you sure you just aren't seeing the parent's pid before the socket times out?

Comment: Could you provide output of "netstat -ap | grep <port>"? There could be a closed TCP connection in TIME_WAIT state in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of all server sockets by *storing them* and then after `fork()`ing have those `close()`d in the child.

Those are the `listen()`ing sockets and the `accept()`ed sockets.

---

**Update:**

Also you might like to use `setsockopt()` to set the option `SO_REUSEADDR` to the socket passed to `bind()`

> SO_REUSEADDR
>
> Indicates  that the rules used in validating addresses supplied in a
>   bind(2) call should allow reuse of local addresses.  For AF_INET
>   sockets this means that a socket may bind, except when there is an
>   active listening
>                 socket bound to the address.  When the listening socket is bound to INADDR_ANY with a specific port then it is not possible to
>   bind to this port for any local address.  Argument is an integer
>   boolean flag.

Comment: Don't you think `close_all_nonestandard_fds();` do that?

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan: yes it does, but that function should just close exsisting fds.

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan maybe, maybe not. What if the "listening socket" is actually set as stdin (which would be the case for servers launched from inetd, among other things). Or perhaps the getrlimit call fails, and not all handles are being closed - only the first 1024.

Comment: @NikB. Listening socket is not set as stdin, and also I checked that getrlimit works fine.